# getContentView() from android BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Is there any way to get `ContentView` from android `BottomSheetDialog` ? In `PopupWindow` , I can get `PopupWindow` 's view by `popupWindow.getContentView()` method. But, I cann't find any method to get `ConentView` from `BottomSheetDialog` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
View contentView = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```